# Serve content cloned from git in apache

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, lamp

I've cloned a PHP repository from git that actually is served in a server with Apache and I want to reproduce it locally. This repository is cloned in:

```
/home/me/test/repository
```

I've also installed Apache in my Ubuntu and it starts fine. Now, I need to do two things:

**1. Load userdir, cgi and rewrite modules**

For this, I loaded the modules by doing:

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
sudo a2enmod cgi
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

But I don't know if have to do any extra thing :/

**2. Serve the content of the repo**

I have no idea of how to do this, because my logic tells me to keep the git structure to be able to push things after modifications.

I know that `DocumentRoot` is in `/var/www/html` and if I create a index.php with a simple instruction, it works fine. But how with the repo?

Comment: Read the repo's read.me. Presumably the source you cloned has its own index.php to bootstrap

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have your repository cloned in `/home/me/test/repository` and your server's `DocumentRoot` is set to `/var/www/html`? Usually the root repository folder works as webserver's document root as well, so simply make a new repository clone in `/var/www/html` or change your `DocumentRoot`.